how convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.AnimationClip>' to 'UnityEngine.AnimationClip
I want to get specific AnimationClip using linq to an array for Animationclip
code :
AnimationClip[] clips = GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;

AnimationClip dieClip = clips.Where(clip => clip.name.Contains("Die")).Select(clip => clip);

error in linq:

Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.AnimationClip>' to
'UnityEngine.AnimationClip' [Assembly-CSharp]

How do I convert that type?
I try casting that type by force :
(AnimationClip)clips.Where(clip => clip.name.Contains("Die")).Select(clip => clip);
and use generic :
clips.Where<AnimationClip>(clip => clip.name.Contains("Die")).Select<AnimationClip, AnimationClip>(clip => clip);

you need a singular, not a enumerable list, so try firstordefault

Also, no need for the final Select(clip => clip) -- that does nothing

If you're going to call First, Single, FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault to get a single item from an enumerable list, there's no need to call Where. Each of those methods will accept the same filter expressions as Where does. In your case, you can drop both Where and Select and just call the most appropriate of those four methods. Given that you're using a filter that could theoretically match multiple items, it might be appropriate to call Single or SingleOrDefault, which both validate that there is no more than one match.

Linq is returning an enumarable, which in this case would be a list of AnimationClips. You are assuming it is a single AnimationClip.
Rather use a method that returns a single instance, or I suppose you can take the first result of the list. BugFinder already suggested using FirstOrDefault.
Either way, using Linq at runtime, particularly for a time-sensitive search, may be a bit of a costly operation where a for loop would probably be better. If this is load-time code then nevermind!
PS. Try to remember and understand exactly what that error is saying. It clearly tells you that the one type is an enumarable list of the other.
Hope this helps.
